# Why does my tofu keep turning out brittle?

Tags: tofu

I've been making my own tofu for a couple weeks now, first making fresh soy milk using my soy milk maker, and then combining the fresh and hot milk in a bowl with tofu coagulant (either gypsum or nigari), let it sit for a while, and then press it.

However, my tofu keeps turning out quite grainy and brittle, easily falling apart.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: I honestly don't know much, but how much coagulant are you using for how much soy milk? How much weight are you pressing with....?

Comment: I'm currently using about a teaspoon for a liter of soymilk, pressing with about 500g of weight for 20 minutes. I'm currently trying to use more weight.

Answer (score 1):

[This recipe](https://www.thespruceeats.com/how-to-make-tofu-1001574) uses more coagulant (1 tablespoon for 3 cups/600g of dried soy beans + 750g of water) and more weight (2.5 pounds), so I think you could also increase one or both of these factors in your next batch.